# Concatenate first line to the end of second line in a text file

Tags: linux, text

I am trying to append first line to the end of second line. I have huge text file where I have to this process for all the entries.

```
 Value="AF" /> 
<ListItem Text="Afghanistan" 


 Value="AL" />
<ListItem Text="Albania"


 Value="DZ" />
<ListItem Text="Algeria"


 Value="AS" />
<ListItem Text="American Samoa"


 Value="AD" />
<ListItem Text="Andorra"
```

The output should be on the lines of:

```
<ListItem Text="Afghanistan" Value="AF" />
<ListItem Text="Albania" Value="AL" />
<ListItem Text="Algeria" Value="DZ" />
```

Can anyone please help me achieve this? Thanks a lot

Comment: Are there 2 blank lines between every 2 blocks? Do you want to keep it in the output?

Comment: yes.. 2 blank lines. no. it's better if they aren't present in output. even if they can't be removed, it's fine... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ sed -e '/^$/d' -e 'N;s/\(.*\)\n\(.*\)/\2\1/' input.txt
```

- `/^$/d` - delete all the blank lines
- `N` - put the next line into the pattern space
- `s` - substitute
- `\(.*\)\n\(.*\)` - matching the first line, followed by newline and
  the second line
- `\2\1` - append the first line to the end of second line by using
  back reference

Comment: wow... really thanks a million :) you're great... :)